# Determine size of input array plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function that takes an integer[] as input.

The whole setup can be found in this question:
[Passing a record as function argument PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716024/passing-a-record-as-function-argument-pl-pgsql)

Short version:
I have an n to m relationship from books to authors with a link table called books_author. I now have a function that looks like this:

```
    create function f_insert_books(title varchar, isbn varchar, publisher varchar,  
      author_id integer[]) returns void as $$
      begin
      --insert book
      --insert link to authors into the books_author table
      end;
    $$ language plpgsql;
```

I now want to add the number_of_authors to the book. Is there an easy way to determine the size of the author_id array or would you recomment passing the "number_of_authors int" as an input parameter?

I found this suggestion, but I am a bit worried about performance in this approach. So maybe there's something easier/faster.
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2000-06/msg00169.php

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`array_length`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT array_length( ARRAY[1,2,3], 1 );
```

The 2nd parameter is the dimension you're interested in. Most arrays are 1-dimensional, so 1 is the right value in most cases.

If you're in fact looking for the length of all the strings in a `text` array, use `array_to_string` with `length`:

```
SELECT length(array_to_string( ARRAY['a','bb','ccc'], '' ));
```

BTW, the article you linked to is 12 years old and appears completely obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more function to get the length of the array - [`cardinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT cardinality(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

It works in the same way for a simple one-dimensional array and there is no need to pass any additional parameter such as array dimension in the [`array_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) function.