# Selecting and passing a record as a function argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

It may look like a duplicate of existing questions (e.g. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716024/passing-a-record-as-function-argument-pl-pgsql)) but they only deal with passing "new" arguments, not selecting rows from the database.

I have a table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_something(row_in my_table) RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    -- does something
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would like to run it on data already existing in the database. It's no problem if I would like to use it from another PL/pgSQL stored procedure, for example:

```
-- ...
SELECT * INTO row_var FROM my_table WHERE id = 123; -- row_var is of type my_table%rowtype
PERFORM do_something(row_var);
-- ...
```

However, I have no idea how to do it using an "ordinary" query, e.g.

```
SELECT do_something(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 123);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: SELECT FROM do_something(SELECT * FROM my_table ...
```

Is there a way to execute such query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a scalar record to that function, this requires to enclose the actual select in another pair of parentheses:

```
SELECT do_something( (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 123) );
```

However the above will **NOT** work, because the function only expects a *single* column (a record of type `my_table`) whereas `select *` returns multiple columns (which is something different than a single record with multiple fields).

In order to return a record from the select you need to use the following syntax:

```
SELECT do_something( (SELECT my_table FROM my_table WHERE id = 123) );
```

Note that this might still fail if you don't make sure the `select` returns exactly one row.

If you want to apply the function to more than one row, you can do that like this:

```
select do_something(my_table)
from my_table;
```